# Cannot Open Remote Connection to Postgres, FirewallD Issue?

Tags: centos, centos7, postgresql, firewalld

I have tried everything I could find to establish a remote connection to my Postgres 9.6 database running on a CentOS 7 gcloud VM.

I have set the following in pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all MYPUBLICIP/24 md5
```

postgres.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

Setup firewalld like in this article: [How to Configure 'FirewallD' in RHEL/CentOS 7 and Fedora 21 - Part 3](https://www.tecmint.com/configure-firewalld-in-centos-7/3/)
Result of `firewall-cmd --list-all`:

```
trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 50.236.122.225/24
  services: postgresql
  ports: 5432/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

There is no interface. I tried adding one using `firewall-cmd --zone=public --change-interface=eth0` but that did change anything.

I tried using iptables instead but without success. Iptables is now removed so it cannot interfere.

Comment: After you made the changes in both `firewalld` and `postgresql`, did you restart each service? Does the client that you're trying to connect from actually have the ip address of `50.236.122.225`? Also, in `pg_hba.conf, instead of `MYPUBLICIP`/24, use `0.0.0.0/0` under `remote connections`.

Comment: Also look into tcpdump output and check if there are any traffic on port 5432.

Comment: @NasirRiley - I tried restarting each after every change. Firewalld will not start up anymore, not sure how I broke it. It now shows the eth0 interface on `firewall-cmd --list-all` though, even though I removed it! Tried changing to 0.0.0.0/0 md5 in postgres config but still connections all time out

Comment: @deflator Your rule is in the `trusted` zone and not in the `public` zone. Be sure that your interface and rules are all in `public`.